# Database Normalisation - stuck with "categories"

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

**Context:**
I'm working on a database of museums and Categories will be one way the user will be able to search. e.g click on "Music" and a list of music related museums turn up. Pretty simple.

**Problem:**
I'm stuck and confused on the Normalisation process of the "Categories" table...

**categories_PK** IF is the entry point to the ID rows table,  how do I reference the actual categories themselves? Such as "Architecture" and "Artists Architects and Writers Homes" in one query? I'm confused — I don't see how the values will be referenced?

As one museum may fall into more than one category, the only other idea I had was to ad a Foreign Key to every category such as Archaeology_PK?
Here's what I've got....

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You need two tables:

```
Categories
MuseumCategories
```

They will look like this:

```
Categories
    CategoryID   (Primary Key)
    CategoryName

MuseumCategories
    MuseumID     (Foreign Key)
    CategoryID   (Foreign Key)
```

The MuseumCategories table connects each specified category to a museum.  Each record in the MuseumCategories table connects one category to one museum.  You can have many such records for the same museum.

Comment: Brilliant, that's really helpful, thanks so much. Does that mean I have to add additional table for every other table I already have too? Such as "DETAILS" "CATEGORIES" "ADMISSION" "LOCATION"? I've got an image I can show...

Comment: @CallMePhilip this structure is a many to many relationship mediated by the table.  If other tables also have a many to many relationship, they may need such a structure too.  If a single 'Details' is shared by multiple other objects and those objects may have multiple details, then yes, it may too need a many to many structure.

Comment: here's what I got...   http://www.graphicsdesigned.co.uk/MuseumSchema.jpg

Comment: @MichaelT thanks for your comment, really helpful. I heard many-to-many relationships are to be avoided. But I don't understand why? So, I understand that I need to add four more "bridging" tables? — this is turning out to be much more complicated than I first thought! I am really grateful for your comments,

Comment: Many to many relationships shouldn't be avoided if that's what you are modeling.  There's no other way to represent them in a relational database.  You only need one table for bridging "categories."

Comment: @CallMePhilip each museum would only have a single row in Details, Admission, and Location.  Thus, for those, the structure you have is one that would work.  Noteing that these are 1:1 relationships, you may find it appropriate to have them actually be columns within the Museums table rather than separate tables of their own (though there is something to be said about splitting apart conceptual groups - I've seen a table with 200+ columns because the designers didn't want to split out conceptual groups (that wasn't fun)).

Comment: hhhhmmm.... so, this really could go a few ways. 1-to-1 or 1-to-many. Well, originally, I just had two tables Museums Details (which contains admission + location + museum details) linked to Categories. But, I think I've been seriously over thinking it... — In conclusion, should I just stick to the original plan and have two tables, Museum (combined with admission, and location) linked to Categories? — keepin' it simple? Will that have any effect on performance? Searchability?

Comment: Your original problem description requires a many-to-many relationship.  If you were only tagging museums with a single Category, then you could get away with a one-to-many and avoid the linking table.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for your comment, helpful stuff as always.

Comment: Sorry to keep going with this, but I really want to fully understand it correctly. Would this design work or is it unnecessarily complicated? — again thanks EVERYONE www.graphicsdesigned.co.uk/Museumscema2.jpg

Comment: Are the other relationships really many to many, or are they one to many?  To find out, go to the tables at the end of the relationships, and ask yourself: "Would this entity be associated with more than one museum?"  For example, can a museum have two different locations?  If the answer is no, then it's a one to many, and you don't need the bridging table.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for your helpful comment, it doesn't make any logical sense for them to be anything other than one to many.Right, I think I MAY finally have it! does this make sense? www.graphicsdesigned.co.uk/Museumscema3.jpg sorry for being so dumb, I am truly thankful for your time and patience.

Comment: @CallMePhilip note that you have over 20 rep now.  You can enter [chat] (The Whiteboard) and discuss things in a more real time and interactive way rather than going through comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you use a bridge table, a table that exists to link your two tables.

So, you have a table MuseumCategory which has at least two columns, Museuem and Category.  Both being foreign keys to their respective tables.

You might want to have other columns, such active or start and end dates, depending upon your system you might want auditing information (created by, date created, approvedby, whatever).